# How To render Stack Screen At the Opening of the App Without Putting it in Drawer Screen

Tags: react-native, navigation, navigation-drawer, react-native-navigation

In Below Image I have Stack Screen In white In Back Side. And Drawer In Front Side. So my Question is How do I remove That Screen Which is in back. from Drawer Screen. I want My drawer Screens Separately and Stack screen Separately. please help.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont understood very well what you want, do you want set background invisible? Or do you want that Drawer to occupy the entiry width of the screen?

Comment: Thank for replying. When I logged In my App. I am Either able to set Drawer at The initial Screen Or My Home screen AT the Initial Screen. By setting Home Screen At initial Screen. I do not know How To set Drawer on that screen. means I dont want my inital screen that "Home screen" In drawer I want that screen separate But when I seprate My drawer is not there

Comment: means I want to render My drawer as well as my stack screen at the opening of the app separately.

Comment: props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer is not a function. (In 'props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer()', 'props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer' is undefined)

Comment: I think I understood what you want, you need have a screen "clone" of you drawer declarated in your stack navigator to use when user set drawer like initial Screen, in this new screen you create the layout similar to your menu. A drawer cant set initial screen directly in a practical way.